# Call javascript function which name is in variable

Tags: javascript, function, variables, call

The problem is next:
Assume that we have a select.
Onchange event we need to call some function, but name of this function kept in variable.
How to call this function ?

Comment: See this answer here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
window[name]()
```

You can call functions by name reference by selecting them as a property of `window` and executing them

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `variableName();` ?

We often pass around callback functions, which might look something like this

```
function doSomething(callbackFunction){
    // some happy code
    callbackFunction()
}
```

Comment: Actually, the OP said the _name_ of the function is in the variable, not (a reference to) the function itself.

Comment: this is what I was looking for - came up on Google for my search