# Javascript - Calling a function name based on a variable

Tags: javascript, function, dynamic, call, eval

I am trying to call a function whose name is defined elsewhere is the code.

Below is sample code:

```
Inner.testFunc = function(node) { 
 var functionName = node.substring(node, to.indexOf('@'));
 // call the function based on functionName
 [functionName + '()']
}

function something() {
 //doing something
};

...
```

Assuming that `functionName = something`, this should try to call the function, but it isn't doing it.

I'm tried using other links such as [Call javascript function which name is in variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871165/call-javascript-function-which-name-is-in-variable) but it didn't help.

I've also tried using eval():

```
eval(functionName + '()');
```

but this returned something about an illegal character...

Comment: What is the value of `functionName` when you `eval` it?

Comment: It has the correct value. Solution is below, the "()" should be outside the first brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `eval` call might not be working; use instead:

```
eval(functionName)(); //note () after the eval statement
```

In your code ensure first that `functionName` is `something`

`console.log(functionName === 'something') //true`

Comment: Wow I didn't even think of that xD It works using eval(functionName)(); Thanks!

Comment: It won't let me, says 3 minutes left =) waiting for the timer to go ^^

Answer (score 2):

If your function is defined in the global scope, you could take advantage of the fact that global variables and global functions can be accessed as properties of the global scope:

```
function something(){ console.log('Works!'); }
window['something'](); // Works!
```

If it is not, perhaps a reference to it is stored as a property of an object:

```
var x = { something : function(){ console.log('Also works'); } };
x['something'](); // Also works
```

Otherwise, it is impossible to access.

Comment: window[] I've tried already and it doesn't work. Event trying to call it directly with window like you've done. I'll be honest, I don't know what is meant by it being in the Global scope, but I'm pretty sure it isn't... I'm running this in an external JS file not in the html one

Comment: being in the global scope means that the definition of the function is not inside another function. In this case, something is not in the global scope: `function() { function something(){} }`. It doesn't matter if the script is external or not.

Comment: Ah I see, in that case it's not in the global scope, it's defined in a function: test.module(){ .... something(){...} .... }

Answer (score 0):

functionName is the return of the substring method, not the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a map of functions with their names as keys as shown below. And then you can pass the output of `substring` to the map and call the function.

```
function myName() {
    console.log("thefourtheye");
}

var functions = {             // map of functions and their names
    name: myName
};

functions["name"]();          // Instead of "name" pass the result of substring
```

Comment: The issue here is that I have around 20 functions from which I could call from, I would need to individually add these to functions?

Comment: @Gary Yup. This will be the efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little more verbose but what about using a case statement to run a function based on the value of node.

Comment: Well this is a slightly simplified version, but later in the code I am cutting three variables to build the function name so it would be a bit too complicated then

Comment: You're not making it easy on yourself are you!